# Cannot invoke 'decodeResponse' with an argument list of type '(modelType: Decodable, data: Data)'

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomRequest {

  var sendingRequest: Codable;
  let url: URL
  var request: URLRequest;
  var device: UIDevice
  var responseMapper: Decodable

  init(request: Codable, url: String, mapper: Decodable){
      self.sendingRequest = request
      self.responseMapper = mapper;
      self.url = URL(string: url)!
      self.request = URLRequest(url: self.url)
      self.device = UIDevice.current
      addDeviceHeaders()
  }

  func addDeviceHeaders(){

      let deviceUDID = device.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

      self.request.addValue(device.name, forHTTPHeaderField: "device-name")

      if (deviceUDID != nil) {
          self.request.addValue(deviceUDID!, forHTTPHeaderField: "device-udid")
      }
  }

  func get() -> CustomRequest {
      self.request.httpMethod = "GET"
      return self;
  }

  func post() -> CustomRequest {
      self.request.httpMethod = "POST"
      return self
  }

  func send(){
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) {data, response, error in
          guard error == nil else {return print("NETWORK ERROR")}
          self.decodeResponse(modelType: self.responseMapper.self, data:data!)
      }
  }

  func decodeResponse<T>(modelType: T.Type, data: Data) where T:Decodable {
      JSONDecoder().decode(modelType, from: data)
  }
}
```

Я только начал изучать Swift, подскажите что я делаю не так!?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут несколько ошибок

1. Для передачи в параметре типа нужно передавать конкретный тип. Это
   значит, что нужно создать свой класс, использующий протокол
   `Decodable`
2. Поскольку метод `JSONDecoder().decode` кидает исключение, мы должны
   его обработать в месте вызова или передать исключение выше и
   обработать его уже там (я выбрал второе)
3. `guard error == nil else {return print("NETWORK ERROR")}` - так
   `print` не будет вызван

Исправленный вариант

```
class CustomRequest {

    class ResponseMapper: Decodable {
    }

    var sendingRequest: Codable;
    let url: URL
    var request: URLRequest;
    var device: UIDevice
    var responseMapper: ResponseMapper

    init(request: Codable, url: String, mapper: ResponseMapper){
        self.sendingRequest = request
        self.responseMapper = mapper;
        self.url = URL(string: url)!
        self.request = URLRequest(url: self.url)
        self.device = UIDevice.current
        addDeviceHeaders()
    }

    func addDeviceHeaders(){

        let deviceUDID = device.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

        self.request.addValue(device.name, forHTTPHeaderField: "device-name")

        if (deviceUDID != nil) {
            self.request.addValue(deviceUDID!, forHTTPHeaderField: "device-udid")
        }
    }

    func send(){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) {data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("NETWORK ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            do {
                try self.decodeResponse(modelType: ResponseMapper.self, data:data!)
            } catch {
                // TODO: Handle error
            }

        }
    }

    func decodeResponse<T>(modelType: T.Type, data: Data) throws -> T where T:Decodable {
        try JSONDecoder().decode(modelType, from: data)
    }

}
```